# How to parse String blackjack game result

Tags: java, parsing

I'm working on my new java app. It is blackjack game analyzer.
Server send blackjack game result to user, my app parse it, and then it shows the game description to user. The game result looks like this: 
`#N145. 20(9♥️,6♠️,J♠️,Q♦️) - 19(8♦️,A♠️)`
Here 145 is the game number, 20 is the casino's score and 19 is the gamer's score.
And this row should be parsed into Game object. Here is Game class:

```
//import

public class Game {
    private final int gameNumber;
    private final boolean casinoWon;
    private final Set<Card> gamerDeck;
    private final Set<Card> casinoDeck;
    private final int gamerScore;
    private final int casinoScore;

    public Game(int gameNumber, boolean casinoWon,
                Set<Card> gamerDeck, Set<Card> casinoDeck,
                int gamerScore, int casinoScore) {
        this.gameNumber = gameNumber;
        this.casinoWon = casinoWon;
        this.gamerDeck = gamerDeck;
        this.casinoDeck = casinoDeck;
        this.gamerScore = gamerScore;
        this.casinoScore = casinoScore;
    }

    //getters
}
```

I've started writing a parser, but I think I'm doing it wrong. Here is a bunch of code from it:

```
//import

public class StringParser {
    public Game parseStringToGame(String inputString) throws ParseException {
        int gameNumber = -1;
        boolean isCasinoWon = false;
        int gamerScore = -1;
        int casinoScore = -1;
        String stringGamerDeck = "";
        String stringCasinoDeck = "";

        Iterator<Character> iterator = stringToCharacterList(inputString).iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            StringBuilder currentObject = new StringBuilder();
            Character c = iterator.next();

            if (c == '#')
                c = iterator.next();
            else
                throw new ParseException();

            if (c == 'N')
                c = iterator.next();
            else
                throw new ParseException();

            while(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                currentObject.append(c);
                c = iterator.next();
            }
            gameNumber = Integer.parseInt(currentObject.toString());
            currentObject = new StringBuilder();
            //c=='.'
            if (c == '.')
                c = iterator.next();
            else
                throw new ParseException();

            //c==' '
            if (c == ' ')
                c = iterator.next();
            else
                throw new ParseException();

            //to be continued

        }
    }

    private List<Character> stringToCharacterList(String s) {
        List<Character> characters = new LinkedList<>();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
            characters.add(c);
        return characters;
    }
}
```

As you see, it looks very disgusting. Is there any more 'advanced' way to parse the string?

Comment: Does the string really contain figures (Unicode characters?) or is it a plain text string? If possible I would look into regular expressions for this, done right you could get a lot of the parsing done with one expression

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `9♥️, 6♠️, J♠️, Q♦️` a score of *35* and not 20?

Comment: As I know, in blackjack rules J is equal to 2, Q is equal to 3, K is equal to 4.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, yes, this string contains only Unicode characters. And what do you mean by "one expression"?

Comment: Interesting, here 10, J, Q and K all have a value of 10. A is either 11 or 1

Comment: I meant one regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp for this task, if output of game is always fixed.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^#N(\\d*).\\s+(\\d*)(.+)\\s+-\\s+(\\d*)(.+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    int gameNumber = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    int gamerScore = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
    int casinoScore = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
    boolean casinoWon = casinoScore - gamerScore > 0;
    Set<Card> gamerDeck  = parseDeck(m.group(3));
    Set<Card> casinoDeck = parseDeck(m.group(5));
```

All you need is to implement parseDeck method.